# No output for System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo and net.exe

Tags: c#-4.0

I do the following in my app :

```
if (!new DriveInfo(elt.driveletter).IsReady)
{
    var messages = new List<string>();
    var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process()
    {
        StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("net.exe", String.Format(
            "use {0}: {1}"
            , elt.driveletter
            , elt.parameters
        ))
        {
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
            , RedirectStandardError = true
            , UseShellExecute = false
        }
    };
    p.OutputDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler((o, arg) =>
    {
        messages.Add(arg.Data);
    });
    p.ErrorDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler((o, arg) =>
    {
        messages.Add(arg.Data);
    });
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();

    if (!new DriveInfo(elt.driveletter).IsReady)
    {
        throw new Exception(String.Format(
            "Cannot map drive {0} - {1}"
            , elt.driveletter
            , String.Join("-", messages.ToArray())
        ));
    }
}
```

The exception gets thrown but the text is always blank after "Cannot map drive {0} - ", how comes `messages` doesn't contain anything?

Comment: What happens if you run the command manually?

Comment: System error 85 has occurred.

The local device name is already in use.

Comment: The documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute(v=vs.110).aspx states that you need a full pathname when UseShellExecute is false. Have you tried the full path to net.exe?

Comment: You simply forgot to call the required BeginOutput/ErrorReadLine() methods.  So your event handlers are never called.  Also don't skip checking the Process.ExitCode so you can verify gross errors.  It is better to [pinvoke WNetAddResource2](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/mpr/WNetAddConnection2.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You simply forgot to call the required BeginOutput/ErrorReadLine() methods.  So your event handlers are never called.  Also don't skip checking the Process.ExitCode so you can verify gross errors.  Fix:

```
    p.Start();
    p.BeginOutputReadLine();
    p.BeginErrorReadLine();
    p.WaitForExit();
    int err = p.ExitCode;
    if (err != 0) throw new Exception("NET.EXE failed with exit code {0}", err);
```

It is better to [pinvoke WNetAddResource2()](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/mpr/WNetAddConnection2.html) instead, less accidents that way.

Comment: What if the process ends just after p.Start() and before the call to p.BeginOutputReadLine() ?

Comment: The output is not going anywhere, sitting patiently in the pipe buffer until you read it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a typo but your first `if` statement should check for `IsReady` instead and throw exception/error when not ready like

```
if (new DriveInfo(elt.driveletter).IsReady)
 //work the process

else
 //throw exception
```

You are not getting any data cause your `message` variable is empty because of the reason that process itself not starting. To check, try printing the `StandardOutput` of the invoked process like

```
p.Start();
Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: No, I need to create the mapping only if the drive isn't available already.

Comment: That means the process itself not starting, probably.